# Mysterious "Segmentation fault" error when running a Fortran program

Tags: fortran, data-science, hdf5, netcdf4

P.P.P.P.S
Finally, I have found out the reason of the problem.

Errors occurs on the variable `vbuf`, which is a `Pointer` type and its shape was defined previously. The shape of `vbuf` supposed to be `(\nland,tidx2-tidx1+1\)` but it was uncorrectly defined. The `SIGSEGV, segmentation fault` may not be useful to resolve the problem.

---

I encountered a "SIGSEGV, segmentation fault" error when running a Fortran program that was reading a netCDF file created by another programming language (Julia or Python). The program was compiled by ifort (intel Fortran Compiler). The error messages were:

```
forrtl: severe (174): SIGSEGV, segmentation fault occurred
Image              PC                Routine            Line        Source
clm.x              000000000086F103  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
libpthread-2.17.s  00002B0BB1AD65E0  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
libhdf5.so.103.1.  00002B0BB296CB60  H5SL_item             Unknown  Unknown
libhdf5.so.103.1.  00002B0BB279B825  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
libhdf5.so.103.1.  00002B0BB27C6960  H5D__read             Unknown  Unknown
libhdf5.so.103.1.  00002B0BB27C5FFF  H5Dread               Unknown  Unknown
libnetcdf.so.15.0  00002B0BB103F4B6  NC4_get_vars          Unknown  Unknown
libnetcdf.so.15.0  00002B0BB103E6E6  NC4_get_vara          Unknown  Unknown
libnetcdf.so.15.0  00002B0BB0FBF78F  NC_get_vara           Unknown  Unknown
libnetcdff.so.6.2  00002B0BB1350CE2  nf_get_vara_real_     Unknown  Unknown
libnetcdff.so.6.2  00002B0BB13AABB9  netcdf_mp_nf90_ge     Unknown  Unknown
clm.x              00000000005BB7B7  gswp3data_mp_ncdf         640  gswp3data.f90
clm.x              00000000005B7EC5  gswp3data_mp_read         538  gswp3data.f90
clm.x              00000000005A2086  gswp3data_mp_metd         325  gswp3data.f90
clm.x              00000000005FC968  forcedata_mp_read          58  forcedata.f90
clm.x              00000000007679B2  MAIN__                     83  CLM.f90
clm.x              0000000000410922  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
libc-2.17.so       00002B0BB1F08C05  __libc_start_main     Unknown  Unknown
clm.x              0000000000410829  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
```

I tracked this error and I am confident that it occurs when I call the `nf90_get_var` function:

```
   SUBROUTINE ncdf_read(fid,vid,tidx1,tidx2,vbuf)

      integer,  intent(in) :: fid
      integer,  intent(in) :: vid
      integer,  intent(in) :: tidx1      ! begin time record to read
      integer,  intent(in) :: tidx2      ! end time record to read
      real(r4), intent(out):: vbuf(:,:)  ! pre-read buffer for time record between <tidx1:tidx2>

      if (fid > 0) then
         write(6,*) 'debug', tidx1, tidx2, nland
         call sanity(nf90_get_var(fid,vid,vbuf,start=(/1,tidx1/),count=(/nland,tidx2-tidx1+1/)))
      end if

   END SUBROUTINE ncdf_read
```

The `sanity` is a irrelated function, which shows a error message. It seems that there is something wrong with the NetCDF or HDF5 library. However, I have carefully checked the HDF5 and NetCDF libraries, and I am sure they are correctly installed. (As described below, I can use a simple Fortran program to read this data.)

Also, a "SIGSEGV segmentation fault" always occurs when there is a memory overflow or a pointer out of bounds. This reason has also been rejected because the input NetCDF field contains only thousands of float numbers.

This program is part of a large model, so I must use Fortran to read data. Now I believe that this issue **is related to some of my environmental variables** or some mysterious errors in Julia/Python script, and I will elaborate on the reasons for making this judgment below. But I can't find the exact reason

### What did I tried

Firstly, I wrote a small Fortran program to read the same data. No errors occurred and the program was able to read the data correctly.

My friend compiled the program and generated the entire model in his environment (we both have the same version of netCDF and HDF lib). He uses the same version ifort compiler as me. However, he was able to read the netCDF data normally, and when **I tried to read the netCDF file, which was created by his Julia script, my Fortran program ran normally**.

Now I have no idea where the problem lies or what ways to correct it. I would greatly appreciate it if someone could provide me with advice

P.S. The Julia script I used to create the input netCDF data are as follows. By the way, I have tried the NetCDF4 or NetCDF4_classic (which do not use HDF lib). The error occurs both way.

```
#!julia

using NCDatasets
using Dates
using DataStructures

...

    fo = Dataset(foname,"c")

    defDim(fo, "lon", 1)
    defDim(fo, "lat", 1)
    defDim(fo, "land", 1)
    defDim(fo, "time", Inf)

    xvar = defVar(fo, "lon", Float32, ("lon",), attrib=OrderedDict("units"=>"degrees_E"))
    yvar = defVar(fo, "lat", Float32, ("lat",), attrib=OrderedDict("units"=>"degrees_N"))
    lvar = defVar(fo, "land", Int32, ("land",), attrib=OrderedDict("compress"=>"y x"))
    tvar = defVar(fo, "time", Float32, ("time",), attrib=OrderedDict("units"=>timunits))
    vvar = defVar(fo, vname, Float32, ("land","time"), attrib=OrderedDict("units"=>varunits,"_FillValue"=>convert(Float32,fillvalue)))

    xvar[:] = clon
    yvar[:] = clat
    lvar[:] = 1 # only digger one grid
    tvar[:] = tim[:]
    vvar[:,:] = var[:,:]

    close(fo)

  end
end
```

P.P.S I used dbg to trace the error message. The output massage are:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00002aaaac6afb60 in H5SL_item () from /ddn_lustre/weiliren/apps/hdf5-2019/lib/libhdf5.so.103
Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install cyrus-sasl-lib-2.1.26-21.el7.x86_64 glibc-2.17-196.el7.x86_64 keyutils-libs-1.5.8-3.el7.x86_64 krb5-libs-1.15.1-8.el7.x86_64 libcom_err-1.42.9-10.el7.x86_64 libcurl-7.29.0-42.el7.x86_64 libgcc-4.8.5-16.el7.x86_64 libidn-1.28-4.el7.x86_64 libselinux-2.5-11.el7.x86_64 libssh2-1.4.3-10.el7_2.1.x86_64 nspr-4.13.1-1.0.el7_3.x86_64 nss-3.28.4-8.el7.x86_64 nss-softokn-freebl-3.28.3-6.el7.x86_64 nss-util-3.28.4-3.el7.x86_64 openldap-2.4.44-5.el7.x86_64 openssl-libs-1.0.2k-8.el7.x86_64 pcre-8.32-17.el7.x86_64 zlib-1.2.7-17.el7.x86_64
```

and using `backtrace` it shows:

```
(gdb) backtrace
#0  0x00002aaaac6afb60 in H5SL_item () from /ddn_lustre/weiliren/apps/hdf5-2019/lib/libhdf5.so.103
#1  0x00002aaaac4de825 in ?? () from /ddn_lustre/weiliren/apps/hdf5-2019/lib/libhdf5.so.103
#2  0x00002aaaac509960 in H5D__read () from /ddn_lustre/weiliren/apps/hdf5-2019/lib/libhdf5.so.103
#3  0x00002aaaac508fff in H5Dread () from /ddn_lustre/weiliren/apps/hdf5-2019/lib/libhdf5.so.103
#4  0x00002aaaaad824b6 in NC4_get_vars () from /ddn_lustre/weiliren/apps/netcdf-2019/lib/libnetcdf.so.15
#5  0x00002aaaaad816e6 in NC4_get_vara () from /ddn_lustre/weiliren/apps/netcdf-2019/lib/libnetcdf.so.15
#6  0x00002aaaaad0278f in NC_get_vara () from /ddn_lustre/weiliren/apps/netcdf-2019/lib/libnetcdf.so.15
#7  0x00002aaaab093ce2 in nf_get_vara_real_ () from /ddn_lustre/weiliren/apps/netcdf-2019/lib/libnetcdff.so.6
#8  0x00002aaaab0edbb9 in netcdf_mp_nf90_get_var_2d_fourbytereal_ () from /ddn_lustre/weiliren/apps/netcdf-2019/lib/libnetcdff.so.6
#9  0x00000000005be393 in gswp3data::ncdf_read (fid=65536, vid=5, tidx1=1, tidx2=2928, vbuf=...) at gswp3data.f90:640
#10 0x00000000005baaa1 in gswp3data::read_files () at gswp3data.f90:538
#11 0x00000000005a4c62 in gswp3data::metdata_read (lon_points=1, lat_points=1, gmask=0xc811c0, lonw=0xc822c0, lats=0xc82280,
    longxy=0xc819c0, latixy=0xc81960, mtair=0xc9a9c0, mqair=0xc9aa00, mpres=0xc9aa40, mrainc=0xc9aa80, mrainl=0xc9aac0,
    mwindu=0xc9ab00, mwindv=0xc9ab40, mdswrf=0xc9ab80, mdlwrf=0xc9abc0, tair_z=0xc9ac00, qair_z=0xc9ac40, wind_z=0xc9ac80)
    at gswp3data.f90:325
#12 0x00000000005ff544 in forcedata::read_forcedata () at forcedata.f90:58
#13 0x00000000007728c8 in colm () at CLM.f90:83
#14 0x0000000000410922 in main ()
#15 0x00002aaaabc4bc05 in __libc_start_main () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#16 0x0000000000410829 in _start ()
```

P.P.P.S
Forgive me for not replying to everyone again, because the problem that has been bothering me for a week suddenly disappeared without any modifications, and I cannot even reproduce it. But I still want to thank @lastchance for his advice, which is very helpful for my other debugging processes in the future

Comment: Without the details, especially the code, it is unlikely anyone can help you.

Comment: @Vladimir F Героям слава Thanks for your advise, I have added some information and I'm not sure if these are helpful. Because I believe these contents are all based on common online examples and have been carefully checked.

Comment: Why are you "confident that it occurs when ..."? After all, neither sanity nor ncdf_read appear in the traceback. What does your line ```write(6,*) 'debug', tidx1, tidx2, nland```, which apparently appears before your candidate problem call, tell you. Can you run it through a debugger, which is likely to give you more information.

Comment: @lastchance Thanks for your reply! In fact the `ncdf_read` appears in the traceback, for example `libnetcdff.so.6.2  00002B0BB13AABB9  netcdf_mp_nf90_ge     Unknown  Unknown` and `clm.x              00000000005BB7B7  gswp3data_mp_ncdf         640  gswp3data.f90`. I have tried the dbg and I will add more information about dbg output.

Comment: Put the line ```write(6,*) shape(vbuf);   write(6,*) "Press enter";   read *``` just before your call to sanity() and state what the output is. (The last part is just to buy time before it crashes.) For future reference - mine as well as anybody else's - there is an overview of NF90_GET_VAR at https://docs.unidata.ucar.edu/netcdf-fortran/current/f90-variables.html#f90-reading-data-values-nf90_get_var